# ReactJs Switch Cases

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

LINE NUMBER 8 IS NOT WOKRING MEANS ADDITON IS NOT BEEN PERFORMED BY MY CODE REST ALL OPERATIONS ARE SUCCESFULL.
Can anyone explain me more about the `${a+b}` as it is just concatenating the two numbers.

```
1    import React, { Component } from 'react'

2    class State6 extends Component {
3        state = { msg: '' }
4        calculate(op) {
5            var a = this.refs.a.value;
6            var b = this.refs.b.value;
7            switch (op) {
8                case 'add':
9                    this.setState({
10                        msg: `${a + b}`
                    });
                    break;
                case 'sub':
                    this.setState({ msg: a - b });
                    break;
                case 'mul':
                    this.setState({ msg: a * b });
                    break;
                case 'div':
                    this.setState({ msg: a / b });
                    break;
                default:
                    this.setState({ msg: "WRONG INPUT" })
            }
        }
        render() {
            return <div>
                <h2>Event Handing, Ex-08</h2>
                Enter no1:             <input type="number" ref="a" /> <br />
                Enter no2:             <input type="number" ref="b" /> <br />
                <input type="button" value="ADDITION" onClick={() => this.calculate('add')} />
                <input type="button" value="SUBTRACTION" onClick={() => this.calculate('sub')} />
                <input type="button" value="MULTIPLICATION" onClick={() => this.calculate('mul')} />
                <input type="button" value="DIVISION" onClick={() => this.calculate('div')} /> <hr />
                {this.state.msg}
            </div>
        }
    }
    export default State6;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class State6 extends Component {
  state = { msg: "" };
  calculate(op) {
    var a = parseInt(this.refs.a.value || 0);
    var b = parseInt(this.refs.b.value || 0);
    switch (op) {
      case "add":
        this.setState({
          msg: `${a + b}`
        });
        break;
      case "sub":
        this.setState({ msg: a - b });
        break;
      case "mul":
        this.setState({ msg: a * b });
        break;
      case "div":
        this.setState({ msg: a / b });
        break;
      default:
        this.setState({ msg: "WRONG INPUT" });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Event Handing, Ex-08</h2>
        Enter no1: <input type="number" ref="a" /> <br />
        Enter no2: <input type="number" ref="b" /> <br />
        <input
          type="button"
          value="ADDITION"
          onClick={() => this.calculate("add")}
        />
        <input
          type="button"
          value="SUBTRACTION"
          onClick={() => this.calculate("sub")}
        />
        <input
          type="button"
          value="MULTIPLICATION"
          onClick={() => this.calculate("mul")}
        />
        <input
          type="button"
          value="DIVISION"
          onClick={() => this.calculate("div")}
        />{" "}
        <hr />
        {this.state.msg}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default State6;
```

// You are adding string with string. In the above case you have to convert your input values to Number. IN ES6 '+' is not only Plus opearator it will concat your string as well. so you need to add converts to numbers to perform Addtion.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked and it's working fine but if you are still facing the issue the I suggest you to use `parseFloat` to make sure that the received input is a proper number so replace below lines

```
 var a = this.refs.a.value;
 var b = this.refs.b.value;
```

with

```
let a = parseFloat(this.refs.a.value);
let b = parseFloat(this.refs.b.value);
```